# How to work with Zoom API to automatically record a meeting

Tags: zoom-sdk

I'm working on an app to interface with with Zoom API.  I'd like to be able to programmatically record Zoom meetings.  Something similar to how a platform like Otter.ai has a bot join your zoom call and records the meeting to their servers.

I'm struggling to figure out where to look on the Zoom API, what this is called, and how to best approach this.

Answer (score 1):

Zoom offers an API for accessing conversation data. To retrieve this data, you'll need to guide your users through a step-by-step configuration [process](https://otter.ai/blog/zoom-sync). Alternatively, there's an option that eliminates the need for user configuration: managing bots.

Creating bots for Zoom, Microsoft Teams, or similar platforms can be quite challenging, as there isn't an official API available for these channels. However, **there is a solution called [recall.ai](https://www.recall.ai/)** that offers an API interface for managing bots during calls.